# Oracle data modeler does not save dmd file

Tags: oracle, permissions, save, data-modeling

trying to save data model on Oracle Data Modeler and it won't save it

I gave all permissions and installed JDK8

```
020-10-20 15:38:22 SEVERE - Can not write document to file: /mbb/pm/Process Model.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mbb/pm/Process Model.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.model.metadata.XMLTransformationManager.saveContentOfObject(XMLTransformationManager.java:4187)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.model.metadata.XMLTransformationManager.saveObject(XMLTransformationManager.java:1684)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.model.metadata.XMLTransformationManager.saveDesign(XMLTransformationManager.java:651)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.model.design.Design.saveAll(Design.java:2428)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.swingui.ControllerApplication.saveAll(ControllerApplication.java:4147)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.swingui.ControllerApplication.saveAsDesign(ControllerApplication.java:3879)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.swingui.ControllerApplication.access$6000(ControllerApplication.java:127)
    at oracle.dbtools.crest.swingui.ControllerApplication$SaveAll$1.run(ControllerApplication.java:2966)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create on windows a local directory with full access for writing for all users, on linux use /tmp  and then write the file to this directory. if it works its a privilege issue (shared volume, network drive etc)